# Is there a way I can limit what a user views in my SQL Server tables that are accessed through the web?

Tags: sql-server

I have a small web application with a SQL Server back end. In the application I have tables such as "Content".  There is content that is specific to one user group. Is there some way that I can limit who sees what rows in a table or is it the case that once I give access to the table then everyone has access. I'm thinking of a web based Content Management System for example. How do those systems limit what people can see if all the data is stored in the same tables?

Comment: You can create [views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) in SQL Server.  They can be used for various purposes, including limiting access to data.  A view for each user group would let you customize the visible data.  For a small system it may be manageable, but it quickly gets out of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most content management systems have some form of matrix between users, roles, permissions, publishing workflow and content. This matrix also typically controls security, access, menus and other associated functionality. Depending on your needs you can look towards open source software for inspiration as the domain quickly becomes complicated.